# Flutter NTP Package , IOS ISSUE

Tags: flutter, dart, ntp, flutter-packages

i am using the ntp function , to get the real time ,

```
await NTP.now();
```

and i got this exception on ios device , but the same function work fine on android !

```
SocketException: OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 54, address = dns.google.com, port = 53945
```

any idea what is wrong ? thanks